# Change bottom border color of selected tab bar item

Tags: react-native, tabnavigator

I have the following code in react-native

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {TabNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import {View} from 'react-native';

class Home extends Component {

  static navigationOptions = {
        title:'Home',
        tabBarLabel:'First'
  };

  render() {
    return <View></View>;
  }

}

const tabOptions = {

    tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor:'white',
        inactiveTintColor:'#D3D3D3',
        style:{
            backgroundColor:'green',
            borderTopWidth:1,
            borderTopColor:'#D3D3D3'
        },
        tabBarSelectedItemStyle: {
            borderBottomWidth: 2,
            borderBottomColor: 'red',
        },
    },
}

const ProductNavigator = TabNavigator({
  First: {screen: Home},
  Second:{screen: Home}
},
tabOptions
);
export default ProductNavigator;
```

This is what it looks like when rendered in Android emulator

[image]

**I want the yellow underline to be RED underline instead.  But my rules for `tabBarSelectedItemStyle` that declare a red underline are not being acknowledged. How do I make the underline of selected tab bar items to be red?**

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To style TabNavigator selected item's indicator you can use [`indicatorStyle`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab#tabBarOptions-for-TabBarTop-default-tab-bar-on-Android).

> **indicatorStyle** - Style object for the tab indicator (line at the bottom of the tab).

**Example**

```
const tabOptions = {    
    tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor:'white',
        inactiveTintColor:'#D3D3D3',
        style:{
            backgroundColor:'green',
            borderTopWidth:1,
            borderTopColor:'#D3D3D3'
        },
        indicatorStyle: {
            backgroundColor: 'red',
        },
    },
}

const ProductNavigator = TabNavigator({
  First: {screen: Home},
  Second:{screen: Home}
}, tabOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case you are using react-native-tab-view

```
import {TabView, TabBar, SceneMap} from "react-native-tab-view";

    const renderTabBar = (props) => (
    <TabBar
        {...props}
        indicatorStyle={{
            backgroundColor: "black",
        }}
        pressColor="#b3bb"
        activeColor={"black"}
        inactiveColor={"black"}
        style={{
            marginTop: 25,
            backgroundColor: "white",
        }}
      />
   );
    //rest of code
```