# How to Customize material-bottom-tabs?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want to customize MaterialBottomTabs, i am trying to do it for long time please help me also i am a novice in react-native.
here i am share screenshot of bottomTab which is i want,[image]

and here i am sharing screenshot of current bottom tab bar[image]

Please help me thank in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To style the tab navigator you have the tabBarOptions prop
use labelStyle to style the label and tabStyle for tabs etc.

to make the text appear in 2 lines you need to set the label width or add padding

to add a line below the active tab use indicatorStyle as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/47025116/13196047

these options are just an example, you need to customize them to your style...

```
const options = {
    style: { height: 36 },
    labelStyle: { fontSize: 12 }, 
    tabStyle: { marginTop: -5 }
    indicatorStyle: { borderBottomColor: 'white', borderBottomWidth: 1 }
}


<Tab.Navigator tabBarOptions={options} >
    <Tab.Screen name="CropDetail" component={CropDetail} />
    <Tab.Screen name="SoilReport" component={SoilReport} />
    <Tab.Screen name="SomeOther" component={Component} />
</Tab.Navigator>
```